# rule of convergence and divergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

i have read in Marsden-Weinstein calculus II book, page : 571 the following

[image]

but for example look at these two series: $ \sum ^{\infty }_{i=1}\left( -2i\right) $ and $ \sum ^{\infty }_{i=1}2^{i} $ . $-2i < 0.5^i$ . the first is a divergent series but the second is convergent

Comment: Which part of the ratio comparison tests do you feel your example contradicts? Be careful not to confuse the given statements with their converses (the converse of a true if-then statement is not necessarily true).

Comment: I think these statements are made confusing by the fact that the conclusion is embedded in the hypotheses. So I sympathise with @mohamed.

Comment: @GregMartin , i edited the question

Comment: @ancientmathematician, the author explains comparison test in detail earlier in the chapter. its just this second case where he ddn't use absolute value. the problem is a series might be diverging (increasing infinitly as example) and the other might be converging because the first is negative in total and the latter is positive. ,this violates his rule

Comment: Note that the first line of math contains the assumption "$b_i>0$ for all $i$". Does this resolve your confusion?

Comment: @GregMartin, that solved the problem thanks